# Is there a way to remove App from iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

Accidentally I used wrong naming convention for my `Bundle ID` in my App, and I want to delete that App from iTunes Connect, is it somehow possible? I already removed from `developer.apple.com > Identifier > App IDs` that certain `Bundle ID`. What else I can do?

App is still in `Prepare for Submission` state.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to do it. To delete an app, this must be approved first.

> Apps that have not been approved yet can't be deleted.

[Transferring and Deleting Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Comment: And if app is approved and then deleted will the app thumbnail dismiss for iTunes app list or only it will be removed from App Store, but symbol keeps exist in iTunes connect? .. you know I have many apps now in iTunes list and I wants to get rid of rubbish

Comment: Both, removed from App Store and from your iTunes Connect.

Comment: Apple have some stupid rules. This is one.

Comment: I was checking for name availability and unintentionally "created" an app that I now can't delete.  This is asinine!

Comment: This is ridiculous…

Answer (score 6):

New feature is added by Apple to delete an app from iTunesConnect. For details, refer to this help document:

[Delete an app from your account](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev28d17ed35)

Answer (score 3):

While you can't delete an app that has not been approved, you can edit and reuse the same app record for a new app.

When I talked to Apple's Developer Support team about a previously rejected and abandoned app in our account, this is the method they suggested as it is possible to edit the bundle identifier, app name and all existing assets prior to submitting for review, essentially making a new app record out of the old one.

We did this, noting the circumstances of the previous rejection in the App Review section and that they did not apply to the new app, and were able to successfully reuse the old record.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to do it. To delete an app from App Store Connect, this must be approved first.

**=> Application Successfully updated and rejectd**

- Provide all details of application and mention Apple ID in mail
- Send mail to eurodev@apple.com
- It will take 2-4 days to remove

  Note: The mail should be send from your register mail-id.

**=> Application Approved**

```
  Check the below like it will show you in details.
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461735/how-to-delete-an-app-from-itunesconnect

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is a way to hide it on App Store.

1. login to your developer console
2. choose your app
3. availability and pricing
4. set the availability to "remove from sale"

It does hide your app on iTunes for all **new users**. Remember, the old users who downloaded that version of app still have access to it.

Thanks,

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Your answer only removes the app for sale from the App Store but doesn't remove it from iTunes (now App Store) Connect.